# Pushing a server by Git?

Tags: git

I have tried the following command unsuccessfully:

```
git push 12.12.12.123:/proj.git master
```

It asks my password, but each time it rejects it.

I used the following commands to set up Git:

```
git --bare update-server-info
chmod a+x hooks/post-update
```

The last command gives me this error:

```
chmod: Cannot access 'hooks/post-update':No such file or directory
```

I am reading [the tutorial](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch06.html#_git_over_ssh_http).

**[Edit]**

I get the following error message after trying to push:

```
bash: git-receive-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do git init in your repo

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html

Here is nice and quick tuturial:
http://toolmantim.com/articles/setting_up_a_new_remote_git_repository

This is a bit longer once

In short to set up git:

```
$ ssh myserver.com
Welcome to myserver.com!
$ mkdir /var/git/myapp.git && cd /var/git/myapp.git
$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/git/myapp.git
$ exit
Bye!
```

and you need ssh://12.12.12.123:/proj.git master

Comment: Thank you! The main problem was finally in my SSH keypair.

Answer (score 2):

You might also need to add your username to the git command, e.g. masi@1.2.3.4:/proj.git. I think this is why you're getting a password error.

I don't believe the ssh:// is necessary.